# Is it safe to assign a unique_ptr to another unique_ptr inside the first one?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This question is confusing, so here's stripped-down version of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A {
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};

class C : public A {
    public:
        int var;
};

int main()
{
    C* c = new C;
    B* b = new B;
    c->var = 3;
    b->a = std::unique_ptr<A>(c);
    std::unique_ptr<A> aa(b);
    aa = std::move(static_cast<B*>(aa.get())->a);
    std::cout << static_cast<C*>(aa.get())->var;
}
```

This is what I do:
 - Make a class that holds a unique_ptr to itself (my specific case was polymorphic so that's what I did here)
 - Make a unique_ptr of that class
 - Assign the outside unique_ptr the value of the inner one

Now, that last step will destroy the object that the unique_ptr was pointing at.  The value I am assigning it is something in that soon-to-be-deleted object.  However, by moving it, it probably isn't in there anymore.

While this code compiles and runs fine (in valgrind too), I was wondering: is this safe?  Is there something nasty that happened that I didn't realize?  Is there any caveats to doing this?

Edit: I forgot to put in virtual destructors.  Pretend all three classes have that.  It's there in my actual code.

Comment: Polymorphism requires `virtual` methods. A virtual destructor would be a good start.

Comment: You definitely don't want a class to hold a `unique_ptr` to *itself*; but it looks like what you really mean is for a class to hold a `unique_ptr` of the same type (like a node in a linked list).

Comment: @Xirema This is a non-polymorphic type currently, so `dynamic_cast` will not work

Comment: Sorry, in writing this code up I forgot to make a virtual destructor.  That's present in my actual code.

Comment: I think this would be fine because you are first moving `aa->a` into a temporary rvalue. At this point `aa->a` is in empty state, so you can safely destroy the outer A through the assignment. It can't have any effect to the inner A, because it has already been moved to the temporary. I don't think the inheritance really matters here, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @zett42 I don't think there are any temporary `unique_ptr`s, only a temporary `unique_ptr&&`. The creation of a temporary r-value of type `unique_ptr` does *not* cause the source `unique_ptr` to release its owned object.

Comment: I agree that the inheritance doesn't matter, though.

Comment: Thinking about it, you are right. Only the *move assignment operator=* of the target unique_ptr will set the source unique_ptr to empty state. Citing from the [reference for unique_ptr move assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D), "Transfers ownership from r to *this as if by calling `reset(r.release())`", so source unique_ptr will be released first before target will be reset(). Still looks fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This is safe.

The underlying issue is how the move-assignment for `unique_ptr` works. Note that an even simpler example, not involving inheritance, that demonstrates the same concern as your code would be a singly-linked list using `unique_ptr`:

```
class Node {
  public:
    unique_ptr<Node> next;
};

// ....

list_head = make_unique<Node>();
list_head->next = make_unique<Node>();
// Delete the head:
list_head = list_head->next;
```

The key question is, does the destruction of the old `*list_head` node (which occurs as part of the assignment operation) also cause the destruction of the node that is being promoted to the head node?

Note that it would be very surprising if `unique_ptr` could not handle this simple case!

According to CppReference, the assignment operator [behaves "as if by calling `reset(r.release())`"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D). This means that `r` (the right hand side, in this case the `unique_ptr` that originally owns the node being promoted) releases ownership of the object *before* the left-hand side `unique_ptr` is set.

The deletion of the object originally owned by the assigned-to `unique_ptr` is actually the *last* step that occurs in the process. In the linked list example, the object being deleted (the old head node) already has a moved-from `unique_ptr` by the time it's destroyed.

---

**Stylistic notes:**

Having the raw pointers `b` and `c` in your code is surprising and confusing; the `unique_ptr`s that eventually own `*b` and `*c` are not *semantically* unique when there are raw pointers floating around pointing to the owned objects. (`unique_ptr::get()` is indeed useful--the weirdness here is that you've got multiple pointers in the same scope pointing at the same objects.)

Using `new` with `unique_ptr` is reasonable but not "best practice." I'd recommend using `make_unique` whenever and wherever possible. This has a benefit in terms of exception safety, but in my opinion it's also semantically clearer.

Comment: `reset(r.release())`...Yep, that's what I was looking up too. Thanks for providing simpler example.

Comment: I just started compiling with c++14 recently and forgot about `make_unique`.  Thanks for that!  I thought I couldn't do it with polymorphic types but apparently `unique_ptr<Derived>` is castable to `unique_ptr<Base>`.